# create json string with slashes not working in proper format?

Tags: php, json, magento

I have a condition and i need to convert this in json format with slashes. i am using json_encode()

```
Condition
(F1 == '14 Pt C2S') && (F2 == '2 x 7') && (F3 == '4 (CMYK)') && (F4 == 'None')
```

I need to convert this with slashes.Can i add slashes in json format.I am using this code.

```
 $condition = "(F1 == '14 Pt C2S')&&(F2 == '2 x 7')&&(F3 == '4 (CMYK)')&&(F4 == 'None')";
   $a = array(
                        'type' => 'field',
                        'field' => $string,
                        'value' => $string1,
                        'condition' => "is"
                        );
                        echo $json = json_encode($a);


                       }
```

It is returing string like that.

```
"{\"type\":\"field\",\"field\":\"1 \",\"value\":[\" \\\\'14 Pt C2S\\\\')\"],\"condition\":\"is\"}""{\"type\":\"field\",\"field\":\"2 \",\"value\":[\" \\\\'2 x 7\\\\')\"],\"condition\":\"is\"}""{\"type\":\"field\",\"field\":\"3 \",\"value\":[\" \\\\'4 (CMYK)\\\\')\"],\"condition\":\"is\"}""{\"type\":\"field\",\"field\":\"4 \",\"value\":[\" \\\\'None\\\\')\"],\"condition\":\"is\"}"
```

But i need string like below. Please help.

```
{\"type\":\"all\",\"value\":1,\"conditions\":[{\"type\":\"field\",\"field\":\"1\",\"value\":\"14 Pt C2S\",\"condition\":\"is\"},{\"type\":\"field\",\"field\":\"2\",\"value\":\"2 x 7\",\"condition\":\"is\"},{\"type\":\"field\",\"field\":\"3\",\"value\":\"4 (CMYK)\",\"condition\":\"is\"},{\"type\":\"field\",\"field\":\"4\",\"value\":\"None\",\"condition\":\"is\"}]}
```

Comment: You want to pass this json to jquery ??

Comment: No i need to save it in database.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to do another json_encode from the strings you get from the first json_encode:

$json = json_encode($a);
$json_with_escape=json_encode($json);

Comment: I have used this and changed the output above.It is showing [] in jason string.Not showing correct format.I Don't understand why it is showing ([" \\) in jason array.i need only single slashes.

Comment: Hi the issue is solved now but when i am inserting values in database the n it strip the slashes. but i need to insert slashes also with string.